# Table captions are always placed below

Tags: floats, positioning, captions, floatrow

I have a problem with table captions in LaTeX. They appear always below the tables instead of above as required by my editor. I've read lots of documentation and everybody says that if you place the `\caption` command before the begin-tabular like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \caption{This caption is supposed to be above the table}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}
     ...
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```

you get it above the table. And, if you place it after the tabular, like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}
     ...
    \end{tabular}
  \caption{This caption is supposed to be below the table}
\end{figure}
```

you get it below. Well. This is not working for me: my captions are ALWAYS placed below the table regardless of the position of my `\caption` command.

I assume this is something wrongly defined in the document template (I'm using book document template) but I can not find the right key to fix it. Can anyone help with this?

This is the preamble of my LaTeX document just in case it helps:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[total={14cm,21cm},top=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, includehead]{geometry}

\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{estilo}

\citationstyle{dcu}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markboth{Prefacio}{Mi manual}

\newfloat{definicion}{h!}{loa}[chapter]
\floatname{definicion}{Definici\'on}
    \floatsetup[definicion]{framestyle=fbox,framearound=object,frameset={\fboxrule1pt \fboxsep10pt},framefit=yes}  

\begin{document}

...
etc.
```

Comment: The placement option `h!` is too few in my opinion. If `h` for "here" does not work because the float doesn't fit there you would get the LaTeX warning "!h float specifier changed to !ht" and the float would be placed on top of the next page.

Comment: Since you have a valid response below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below its vote count. This shows that the answer helped you, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). If you are not happy with the answer please state so and the reason as a comment below it. Thanks.

Answer (score 38):

This is caused by the `floatrow` package. If you don't use that package, the caption would be placed above.

With `floatrow`, I would use a `table` environment instead of `figure` and specify the table style:

```
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan, I had to keep on using the floatrow package so using the table style worked just fine!

Comment: Please remember to accept a solution if it works!  @Stefan you've saved me a lot of hassle too.  Thanks!!

Comment: @M.Tibbits: You need to add `@ssalonso` to your comment, otherwise he is not notified. This only works for the first user mentioned like that. The author of the post the comment is for (here Stefan) is always notified anyway. Note that answers can only be accepted by the question author, not even by moderators. I added a comment below the question but he wasn't here since Dec 21st so it is unlikely he is coming back.