# How to put table caption on top without using float or floatrow package

Tags: tables, floats, positioning, captions, floatrow

I have got some very simple table; something of the sort:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    1 & 2 \\ \hline
    3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{This is a table description that should be on top of the table.}
\end{table}
```

I am trying to produce a table with the caption on top, but I have one handicap: the style sheet does not allow the use of the `float` or `floatrow` package. This proves quite complicated, cause I can't use the solutions provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22751/how-to-force-table-caption-on-top) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6573/table-captions-are-always-placed-below). But apparently it can be done, as I've seen publications that manage it. What's their secret?

Comment: Doesn't it work to place `\caption{...}` _before_ `\begin{tabular}...`?

Comment: Hmm, I had no things could sometimes be so simple in LaTeX. :-)

Comment: @cgnieder an answer? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Placing `\caption{...}` *before* the `tabular` environment works (unless perhaps you're using some non-common document class):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{This is a table description that should be on top of the table.}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    1 & 2 \\ \hline
    3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]